# Catch failed NSParameterAssert in ObjC without exiting

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, exception

I want to test a method which doesn't return anything. The method starts by asserting that a parameter doesn't contain an illegal value:

```
- (void) someMethod:(NSString*)param {
    NSParamaterAssert(param != @"0");
    // more code
}
```

In my testing code I want to make sure that illegal values are caught, but I don't want the program exiting during testing. In python I can try: except: to catch it. Is there an equivalent in Objective C? Am I using assertions incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up "**Exceptions**" and their "**Handling**" with *assertions*.
(Find more information on assertions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29), "Exception Handling" is also on wikipedia but unfortunetaly I'm only allowed to post 2 links).

*Assertions* are normally not to be used as a way **to preserve your method/program from** (usually serious) **errors** (like wrong function behavior in special cases). *Assertions* are for example used with verification of programs.

You want to **handle exceptions** (like wrong parameters in your case).
A good starting point for doing so is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html) (ObjC only).

Comment: Thanks, a combination of NSException and "@try @catch @finally" does the job nicely.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, `NSAssertion` is used to double-check assumptions made in one's code—an assertion should only fail because you've made a mistake in your code, not because of invalid arguments or unexpected conditions.

`NSException` is used for things like invalid arguments and so on and therefore is a better fit for what you're talking about (but outside of testing it's not standard practice to `@catch` an `NSException`  and continue execution: you would instead just do some error reporting before terminating).

Here's how you'd use `NSException` in your situation. First, change `someMethod:` as follows:

```
- (void) someMethod:(NSString*)param  {
    if (param == @"0") {
        [NSException raise:@"Invalid param value" format:@"param of 0 is invalid"];
    }
    // more code
}
```

Then when you call `someMethod:`

```
@try {
    [yourObject someMethod:@"0"];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"main: Caught %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
}
@finally {
    //any code that should be executed whether or not the exception is raised
}
```

Based on your comment, I guess you'd want to set some kind of flag in the `@catch` block, and if the flag isn't set (i.e., an exception wasn't thrown), then terminate.

P.S. Just so you know, for situations when you want to react errors during regular program execution (as opposed to testing), `NSError` is more idiomatic.

Comment: I'm glad to see an example of how to use NSError, but @Jurlie is correct that I don't want to be adding parameters to the method - I just want to externally verify it's working without recoding it. I think NSException might be more appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make it clear in my question, but I want the program to exit if the method is passed a malformed parameter. Then I want the testing code to check the parameter checking, and exit only if a malformed parameter is allowed through.